# Basic of JSON binary representation

Tags: json, bson

I'm trying to understand JSON and BSON.

JSON spec only shows how this is a cross-language way to specify an "object", and if I am correct normally it is stringified for transferring information between computers.

When it is stringified, are numbers like `5` just using the standard utf8 code, and a string like `'5'` only adding the quotes around it ?

But how is this UTF8 representation of the string typed again such that `5` is again a number? If this is inferred by having or not quotes before this process would be quite slow ?

Basically the question is what binary representation does JSON follow and how it is deserialized (at a high level way) to recover the data types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how this works. JSON per spec is always UTF-8. The "type" for deserialization is inferred from the syntax/notation (it's dynamic typing in JavaScript anyway). In the implementation, for some naive methods I would assume

- if the implementation is done using a higher-level programming language (as a "host"), it's constructs could help with converting an UTF-8 code-point (or ideally & more likely the whole sequence/string) to the internal binary representation of the machine/runtime as indicated/supported by a "type"
- if it's doing some low-level stuff (like implementing the higher string-to-internal-binary-numerical-representation-of-a-"type" constructs of a programming language), there's probably some clever bit-shifts that can be done

The latter because representing decimal numbers in UTF-8 does neither use the lower nor the higher ranges of ASCII in UTF-8, so these are then "lost"/unused in comparison to a binary scheme (which is the optimum for binary/digital machines?). So all that's needed, I guess, would be to subtract or bit-shift the binary offset the decimal numbers have for their ASCII codepoints as in UTF-8, and then proceed to the next byte from the input and do the same, as it's known that there won't be other characters in the JSON numeric literal, so there's no UTF-8 byte chaining to get to its many other character code-points. For comparison, Base64 another similar encoding scheme of using (some of) ASCII (which means, not more as a byte, but with still more loss of course for unused code-points/bits than with pure binary).

Advantages of these schemes are of course that the notation/representation in JSON/BSON/Base64 are plain-text, so they can be viewed/opened, sometimes even read/edited in text-oriented tools/applications. This also reduces the ambiguity of what the binary encoding might mean, as the problematic part is to recognize the scheme/format in the first place. Once it's known/assumed that the source is JSON/BSON, then it can be left to the parser/notation to convert the ASCII/UTF-8 to whatever internal (machine or other, could be any other scheme) representation might be needed (demarshalling, deserialization).

With binary (or actually electronic signals/flows, the machine's only language) as well as with all the character encodings and JSON/BSON, the machine doesn't know beforehand how to interpret these, to which parser to pass these, etc. Made worse as binary can come from many sources, each with different internal/machine representation, or the many different character encodings. So either there's some declarative wrapper/envelope or metadata that comes with the data payload, which can per some standardized method bootstrap it's interpretation per dispatch to the corresponding parser/processor, or 1. the user has to 2. choose the 3. tool/app to be used on the data. That's 3 design flaws/failures in this approach. Or the encoding-scheme/notation is determined heuristically or per [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), but then some chunks of the input have to be read in advance just to choose a fitting parser/processor, which is even more overhead on top. So if already knowing it's JSON/BSON and/or choosing a JSON/BSON parser to apply on the input, then of course it's easy, and there's just the memory + computational overhead to convert the external notation/representation in ASCII bytes as used in UTF-8 to whatever the machine or (language/parser) implementation internally uses to, for example, perform arithmetic on these numbers once read in + converted.

Main point/benefit is, using such string serialization, the machine-/implementation-specific details of internal number representation can be hidden/abstracted away from the external data exchange. JavaScript as an interpreted language probably doesn't want to spec some schemes of its own for binary, machine-oriented representation of its data types, because the whole point of JavaScript and interpreted languages is precisely avoiding to have to do any of that. Same goes for it's code, as it's non-compiled, not natively executable. In a way, JavaScript's syntax/notation, as well as in it's typical implementations/practice, is very inefficient to have the code only in ASCII text form/encoding around, and no support/model to get it's code compiled and natively executed on machines/operating-systems. Of course there's likely some who compile it, maybe WASM might become it's byte-code virtual-machine, but nothing in it's specification which would keep the current JavaScript implementations from diverging in their internal representations. External plain-text notations/serializations like JSON or the JavaScript language help avoiding the incompatibilities between the internal implementation details.

> cross-language way to specify an "object"

I think such framing is somewhat exaggerated. Yes, sure, it can and is used for that. But then, there are a number of problems:

- The "types" assumed/baked in there are JavaScript's types (or, granted, some "generic" notion of standard/basic types). Other systems, languages, machines may have other types, for which JavaScript's/JSON's/BSON's type assumptions might not apply, or these can even be incompatible. To make a wild example, if there would be an object-oriented implementation on a 7-bit-byte big-endian machine that has two int32 types (even as this makes no sense), which may or may not be equal in its internal binary representation, but at least different in the kinds of operations that can be performed on these types (so the type information is used to apply some constaints or optimization), then to represent it in JavaScript's object notation, additional typing information needs to be added into the payload (which is of no meaning for a non-supporting/unaware JavaScript implementation for as long as there's no standardized type support or declaration for these, much less a compatible implementation in the receiving/loading language), which makes it even more inefficient. Or then, JSON is fine with anonymous objects inside arrays, other languages/systems would need to support it with some overhead. Or there's no such notion as classes in its notation/externalization, which may or may not be helpful with other object systems. Indeed rare cases, but there's no universal silver bullet (yet) if going with JSON's string serialization for objects.
- JSON is a notation for structuring text-oriented data, per it's default usually in a hierarchical form (and OK, BSON for binary with some "common"/JavaScript type hints/indicators). But object-systems are more than that. Obviously, it would be a very dangerous/foolish idea under the current conditions to embed JavaScript code into JSON (but BSON does it?!?) and pass it to `eval()` for execution. I mean, of course it's a great idea and the main appeal for JavaScript and it's popularity/adoption in the first place, and it might be fine if it's just your own code or just local or in the browser sandbox, but for object systems to exchange data amongst themselves, which might be "messages"/code, is far from trivial to make it sufficiently "secure" with I think all known interop and serialization/deserialization schemes/methods. Therefore, obviously, JSON doesn't support it, and not sure if BSON allows just the data to be declared to be JavaScript code (by the way, when will they add types for all the other languages? Or is it limited to always only use JavaScript to represent code in this "object notation") but implementers know that they better should never, ever execute it?
- JavaScript has JSON, but other languages have other object serialization (and even more importantly, more and better interop than JSON Web APIs!), and JavaScript/JSON is at an additional disadvantage because it mainly lives inside the browser sandbox as the obvious security requirement (because doing software deployment, remote-code execution here from untrusted sources), so it doesn't talk much with the outside world. Servers do, but they also may use any other format/notation, be it to talk in other languages/protocols/clients, or with more object-systems, or do text-oriented or data exchange, in which case JSON primarily targeting JavaScript in a browser isn't necessarily particularly attractive.
- There might not be JSON (and JSON type deserialization/conversion/demarshalling) support in/for other languages. Of course, can be added, but so can for any other serialization scheme or data exchange format. Probably only matters if talking with JavaScript in a browser on/for the WWW, or a server that often happens to talk to JavaScript in browsers and doesn't support anything else.

So yes, these plain-text formats (using ASCII/UTF-8 as encoding) as notation for externalizing/serializing data, often also to structure data/text, help with abstracting away the implementation details, and that's the source of some inefficiencies because efficiency is gained from optimizing implementation and/or machine details (given there's no code/algorithms expressed in the data exchange format, which would get executed and do something, and would hence be subject to optimization, in contrast to their memory + performance costs for mere notation/transmission). Serialization as ASCII/UTF-8 strings gains some compatibility/abstraction at the cost/expense of some memory/bandwidth + performance, a tradeoff judging the former to be more important/beneficial.

Additionally there's many assumptions about the model, types, etc., some of which might be incompatible between systems, it's just JSON assumes its own to be somewhat "universal"/common via 1. being very simple/primitive/limited and 2. being pretty popular/widespread.

Comment: will come back to it later, seems interesting but may be over my head, thank you